# python on OSX and echo -n

Tags: python, ruby, bash, unix, zsh

Context: I ran [this snippet](http://paste.ubuntu.com/536356/) on my Mac and noticed the string `-n` sprinkled in the garbled output. The answer is that `sh` on Ubuntu understands the `-n` flag while `sh` on my Mac does not.

[image]

As you can see, python is sending to stdout the string `"-n abc\n"` rather than the expected `"abc"`.

Is the `os.system` call unable to separate `-n` and `abc`? Happens with both zsh (the inverted `%` is zsh's way of indicating an EOF) and bash, though if I am not mistaken no shells should be invoked by the python-call (not because I read anything that says so, but based on my common sense) (edit: turns out i'm totally wrong and system runs a subshell)

See how ruby does:

[image]

And some more testing:

[image]
Looks like the script is sent to `sh` but the environment variable for the shell at that point is still `zsh`. Makes sense. I did nothing to clean out the environment... Maybe `sh` doesnt automatically set `$SHELL`.

Comment: its working correctly on my system my `Python version 2.6.6`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system) state:

> [`os.system`] is implemented by calling the Standard C function system()

Follow through to [the man page for C's `system`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system):

> **system() executes a command specified in command by calling /bin/sh -c command**, and returns after the command has been completed. During execution of the command, SIGCHLD will be blocked, and SIGINT and SIGQUIT will be ignored.

Emphasis is mine.

[The man page for echo](http://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/1/echo/) explains it:

> Some shells may provide a builtin echo command which is similar or identical to this
>        utility.  Most notably, the builtin echo in sh(1) does not accept the -n option.
>        Consult the builtin(1) manual page.

And you can confirm this yourself:

```
$ sh -c "echo -n hello"
-n hello
$ bash -c "echo -n hello"
hello
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted in [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system), `os.system` executes the command in a subshell. Depending on your system, it may use a shell whos `echo` command doesn't understand `-n`.

If you want to ensure it uses your shell of choice, use `subprocess.call` with the `shell=True` and `executable='<shell>'` options instead of `os.system`.

Answer (score 0):

what about this?
`python -c 'import subprocess; subprocess.call(["echo", "-n", "abc"])'`
tested on osx and working properly